# Не сохраняются cookies в iframe

Tags: java, ios, spring, cookie

Есть приложение сообщества для ВКонтакте, которое является сайтом, написанным на `Spring Framework`. В desktop версии сайта и мобильном официальном клиенте оно открывается через iframe. При этом в desktop/web версии и клиенте под Android cookies сохраняются, а в клиенте под iOS - нет.

Просмотр логов запрос показал, что соответствующие заголовки cookies отправляются в ответе успешно (переменная JSESSIONID):

```
"X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
"X-XSS-Protection": "0",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"Expires": "0",
"X-Application-Context": "application:production",
"Set-Cookie": "JSESSIONID=8FBFE176EE744442586F034B10EC2F8F;path=/;HttpOnly",
"Location": "https://neon.traffox.ru/",
"status": "302"
```

Под всеми устройствами (Android, Desktop/Web) кроме IOS при следующем запросе этот заголовок приходит:

```
"cookie": "JSESSIONID=8FBFE176EE744442586F034B10EC2F8F"
```

Если открыть сайт напрямую в браузере под iOS, то cookies также успешно сохраняются, то есть проблема либо в iframe, либо в клиенте iOS.

Можно ли как-то исправить?

Comment: Это?
https://gist.github.com/iansltx/18caf551baaa60b79206

Comment: @LEQADA, пробовал - не работает. Читал, что такой вариант в последних версиях iOS не будет работать из-за новых настроек по умолчанию.

Comment: Да, проблема именно и iframe. И ты не первый кто с этим столкнулся и не последний. Вот тут есть хорошая статья, которая все тебе объяснит и наглядно покажет как делать с примерами.
https://geektimes.ru/post/112077/

Comment: @Profesor08, статья хорошая, но проблему с iOS приложением очень решает. Открывать новую вкладку не получится автоматом, потому что будет сразу предлагаться выбор, где её открыть, что будет сильно смущать пользователя.